# ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, webrtc

```
import {useState,useEffect,useRef} from 'react'
import {socket} from './socket'
import Audio from './Audio'

export default function Home() {

    const [connected,setConnected] = useState(false)
    const [streams,setStreams] = useState(undefined)
    const peers = useRef({})
    const myStream = useRef({stream:undefined})

    var ICE_SERVERS = [
        {urls:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}
    ];
    useEffect(()=>{

        function join_chat_channel(channel, userdata) {
            socket.emit('join', {"channel": channel, "userdata": userdata});
        }
        function part_chat_channel(channel) {
            socket.emit('part', channel);
        }
            //get our voice media and store reference
            navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.msGetUserMedia);

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({"audio":true, "video":false})
                .then(function(stream) { /* user accepted access to a/v */
                    console.log(stream)
                    myStream.current.stream = stream
                })
                .catch(function() { /* user denied access to a/v */
                    console.log("Access denied for audio/video");
                })


        socket.on('connect', ()=>{
            console.log("COnnected")
            join_chat_channel("room0", {'whatever-you-want-here': 'stuff'});
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
            console.log("disCOnnected")
        });

        socket.on('addPeer', function(config) {
            //if(streams == undefined){return}
            console.log('Signaling server said to add peer:', config);
            var peer_id = config.peer_id;
            if (peer_id in peers.current) {
                return;
            }
            var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
                {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
                {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]} 
            );

            const cop = {...peers.current}
            cop[peer_id] = peer_connection
            peers.current =  cop

            console.log("Peer id's are ",peers.current)

            peer_connection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    socket.emit('relayICECandidate', {
                        'peer_id': peer_id, 
                        'ice_candidate': {
                            'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                            'candidate': event.candidate.candidate
                        }
                    });
                }
            }


            console.log("The stream is ",myStream.current.stream)
            if(myStream.current.stream){
                peer_connection.addStream(myStream.current.stream);
            }
            if (config.should_create_offer) {
                console.log("Creating RTC offer to ", peer_id);
                peer_connection.createOffer(
                    //gets the local desc -> local sdp
                    function (local_description) { 
                        console.log("Local offer description is: ", local_description);
                        peer_connection.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                            function() { 
                                socket.emit('relaySessionDescription', 
                                    {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_description,'msg':"SENDING OFFER"});
                                console.log("Offer setLocalDescription succeeded"); 
                            },
                            function() { Alert("Offer setLocalDescription failed!"); }
                        );
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log("Error sending offer: ", error);
                    });
            }
        });

        socket.on('sessionDescription',async function(config) {
                    console.log('Remote description received: ', config);
                    var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                    console.log("peers are ",peers.current)
                    console.log("peeer is ",peers.current[peer_id])
                    var peer = peers.current[peer_id]; //already set during add peer(RTC Connection)
                    console.log("REMOTE OFFER RECEIVED FROM",peer)
                    var remote_description = config.session_description;

                    if(config.msg == 'SENDING OFFER'){
                        console.log("FROM NEW JOINEE")
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Answer from old one")
                    }

                    var desc = new RTCSessionDescription(remote_description);


                    console.log("conection state",peer.connectionState)//prints new

                    try{
                        var s = await peer.setRemoteDescription(desc)
                        if(remote_description.type == 'offer'){
                            console.log("yes")
                            console.log("received offer from ",peer)
                            let local_desc = await peer.createAnswer()
                            console.log("local desc is ",local_desc)
                            await peer.setLocalDescription(local_desc)
                         socket.emit('relaySessionDescription', {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_desc,'msg':"SENDING ANSWER"});
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        console.log("ERROR",e)
                    }
                })

                socket.on('iceCandidate', function(config) {
                    var peer = peers.current[config.peer_id]; //get the peer RTC connection
                    var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
                    console.log("adding ice candidates")
                    peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice_candidate));
                });

                socket.on('removePeer', function(config) {
                    console.log('Signaling server said to remove peer:', config);
                    var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                    // if (peer_id in peer_media_elements) {
                    //     //peer_media_elements[peer_id].remove();
                    // }
                    if (peer_id in peers.current) {
                        peers.current[peer_id].close();
                    }

                    //delete peers[peer_id];
                    //delete peer_media_elements[config.peer_id];
                });

        
    },[])


    return (
        <div>
           {myStream ? <Audio stream={myStream.current.stream}></Audio> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the react code and problem is with the setRemoteDescription , other stackoverflow posts were suggesting the problems could be related to setting descriptions in the wrong order but i am not sure if that's the problem .
The error i keep getting is **ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable**

This is the socket server

```
const PORT = 8080;

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const https = require('https')
var http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
  });


server.listen(PORT, null, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + PORT);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    res.send("hi")
});



var channels = {}; //diff rooms
var sockets = {};  //diff users


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.channels = {};
    //THe socket joined is  ox0k_K-rEafWXHF-AAAA
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    console.log("["+ socket.id + "] connection accepted");
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        for (var channel in socket.channels) {
            part(channel);
        }
        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] disconnected");
        delete sockets[socket.id];
    });


    //join certain channel to emit msg's to only those channels
    socket.on('join', function (config) {
        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] join ", config);
        var channel = config.channel;
        var userdata = config.userdata;

        //if socket already in that room
        if (channel in socket.channels) {
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] ERROR: already joined ", channel);
            return;
        }

        //
        if (!(channel in channels)) {
            //create that channel if none is available
            console.log("CREATING NEW CHANNEL")
            channels[channel] = {};
        }

        //INFORM OTHERS IN CHANNEL TO CONNECT TO THIS NEW USER IN THIS PARTICULAR CHANNEL
        let users = channels[channel]
        //{id:socketInfo}
        for (id in users) {
            //create connection between the 2 of them
            console.log("EMITING")
            channels[channel][id].emit('addPeer', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'should_create_offer': false});
            socket.emit('addPeer', {'peer_id': id, 'should_create_offer': true});
        }

        //config new joinee
        channels[channel][socket.id] = socket;
        socket.channels[channel] = channel;
    });

    function part(channel) {
        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] part ");

        if (!(channel in socket.channels)) {
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] ERROR: not in ", channel);
            return;
        }

        delete socket.channels[channel];
        delete channels[channel][socket.id];

        for (id in channels[channel]) {
            channels[channel][id].emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': socket.id});
            socket.emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': id});
        }
    }
    socket.on('part', part);

    socket.on('relayICECandidate', function(config) {
        var peer_id = config.peer_id;
        var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] relaying ICE candidate to [" + peer_id + "] ");

        //if other peer is still in connnection
        if (peer_id in sockets) {
            sockets[peer_id].emit('iceCandidate', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'ice_candidate': ice_candidate});
        }
    });

    socket.on('relaySessionDescription', function(config) {
        var peer_id = config.peer_id;
        var session_description = config.session_description;
        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] relaying session description to [" + peer_id + "] ");
        console.log(config.msg)
        if (peer_id in sockets) {
            console.log("SENDING SESSION")
            sockets[peer_id].emit('sessionDescription', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'session_description': session_description,'msg':config.msg});
        }
    });
});
```